# List comprehension with pattern match in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have one list named *columns*, and I have to create one nested list based on a split of the elements (the first three).

For example, I will divide this element '101 Drive 1 A' in '101 Drive 1' and make a group.

```
columns = ['101 Drive 1 A','101 Drive 1 B','102 Drive 2 A','102 Drive 2 B','102 Drive 2 C','103 Drive 1 A']
```

The output will look like this:

```
[
  ['101 Drive 1 A', '101 Drive 1 B'],
  ['102 Drive 2 A', '102 Drive 2 B', '102 Drive 2 C'],
  ['103 Drive 1 A']
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

columns = ['101 Drive 1 A', '101 Drive 1 B', '102 Drive 2 A', '102 Drive 2 B', '102 Drive 2 C', '103 Drive 1 A']

groups = defaultdict(list)
for column in columns:
    key = column[:3]
    groups[key].append(column)

res = list(groups.values())
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[['101 Drive 1 A', '101 Drive 1 B'], ['102 Drive 2 A', '102 Drive 2 B', '102 Drive 2 C'], ['103 Drive 1 A']]
```

A more robust alternative, that is going to work for any number at the beginning of the string, is to use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

groups = defaultdict(list)
for column in columns:
    key = re.match("\d+", column).group()
    groups[key].append(column)

res = list(groups.values())
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ittertools' *[grouby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)* directly:

```
from itertools import groupby

mask = [list(group) for k, group in groupby(columns, lambda s: s.partition(' ')[0])]
print(mask)
```

Gives #

```
[
  ['101 Drive 1 A', '101 Drive 1 B'],
  ['102 Drive 2 A', '102 Drive 2 B', '102 Drive 2 C'],
  ['103 Drive 1 A']
]
```

Comment: 1) Re *"`ittertools`"*: Not *"`itertools`"*? 2) What do you mean by "Gives #"?